# dojo.dialog.change size after content has been set

Tags: dojo

```
require(["dojo","dojo/dom-attr"], function(dojo, domAttr){
    var dlg =dijit.byId("my_dialog");       
    domAttr.set(dlg, "content", "this is a text");


    //dlg.set("dimensions", [400, 200]);
    //dojo.style("my_dialog", "width", "300px");                    
    //dlg.resize({h: 500, w: 500});
});
```

I have a dijit.dialog. I set its text dynamically but the dialog's size is way too big. i've tried the three things commented above to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set property `style` with the right dimension for your `dijit/dialog`.

In the following example we set dimension width to 500px setting inline CSS for dialog dom element.

Live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/358rjoch/

```
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){
    myDialog = new Dialog({
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 500px"
    });
});
```

---

```
<button onclick="myDialog.show();">show</button>
```

---

Alternatively you can use only CSS (no inline), for example you can give an ID to your dialog widget and use a CSS selector for its style.

Live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/o15mbodm/

```
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){
    myDialog = new Dialog({
        id:"myDialog", // your id here
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "Test content."
    });
});
```

---

```
#myDialog{
  width: 500px;
  height:400px;
}
```

You can find a detailed list of methods and properties for `dijit/dialog` widgets at the following link:

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/Dialog